# Spring-Boot env variable change while service up and running

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

Spring boot microservice is up and running with all configuration set in environment variables. But Service is not reading updated environment variable value once server started. Is there anyway to achieve this?

I have tried starting with microservice with env variables( one of them is retry.count=3) and working fine. But when i update retry.count to 5 i need to restart the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible when you use environment variables only. But you can create class with `@Value` annotation. On application startup it loads value from environment variable. Then you can update this value from code with setter method.

`@Value("${retry.count}")
private String retryCount;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mean the same as you mentioned. These values are read and set at start of application. Is there any way to read updated value during server up?

Comment: If you update environment variable (not config class variable in your application), updated value should be read on Spring Boot start.

Comment: So i understand that updated env value gets into action only after service restart. Right?

Comment: Yes. Environment variables are loding during JVM start. You can update your config class fields but this information is not propagated back. And after JVM start env variables are not loaded anymore.